# How use posgres or mongo databases in pcf-dev(pivotal cloudfoundry dev)?

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, cloud-foundry

dev (replacement of micro cloud foundry) I saw 3 services in marketplace mysql, redis and Rabbit, buy I need use mongo and postgres for my stuff, there is any easy way to add it in this deployment?

Comment: I think you need to add those tiles.

Comment: which files? could you provide a link please? also, I am not sure how/where to add it, should I use the cf client console?

Comment: Well. that works for non dev PCF version, not what I am looking for, thanks anyway

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PCF Dev does not currently include support for MongoDB or Postgres service instances. It is also not currently possible to install tiles or BOSH releases.

All of these things may be supported eventually, but for now, you can run MongoDB or Postgres on your host system and create a user-provided service instance using the cf CLI.

Here's an example for Postgres: https://docs.tibco.com/pub/bwcf/1.0.0/doc/html/GUID-D7408016-8C7B-4637-BCC5-EDD9D5C52267.html

Note that you must use `host.pcfdev.io` instead of `localhost` to refer to the host system (instead of the PCF Dev VM). In the example above, your URL might look like:

`url> postgresql://host.pcfdev.io:5432/postgres`

(Also note that `host.pcfdev.io` may actually be `host2.pcfdev.io` if your system domain is `local2.pcfdev.io` instead of `local.pcfdev.io`)

~Stephen Levine, PCF Dev Product Manager

Comment: I tried this but can't get Spring to bind to the user provided service and wire up Postgres. Docs https://spring.io/blog/2015/04/27/binding-to-data-services-with-spring-boot-in-cloud-foundry suggest that tags give a hint as to what type of datasource to create but I don't see a way to specify tags using `cf cups`.